# How upload large number of files to a google storage bucket?

Tags: file, numbers, cloud, storage, gsutil

Which is the right way to upload a specific folder from a PC with thousands of files and subfolders to a Google Storage Bucket?

I tried with gsutil command:

```
gsutil -m cp -r myfolder gs://my-bucket
```

But transfer stops and only upload a few of hundred files until drops a Python error.

Is this the right way for do this?

Microsoft Azure Storage has a (wonderful) graphical tool called Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer and with command `azcopy` works perfectly, upload all thousand of files so quickly.

Comment: What error do you get? Do you have files larger than 8MiB? If you have large files try to use [parallel composite uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#parallel-composite-uploads). Please read carefully the best practices for [uploading data](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices#uploading) and avoid using [sequential filenames to avoid creating hotspots](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices#naming).

Answer (score 1):

You can use gsutil with the -R recursive flag to upload all the files and sub-directories.

```
gsutil -m cp -R dir gs://my_bucket
```